# Google app engine datastore on localhost

Tags: google-app-engine

I am having an already created python application created on google app engine, I have successfully installed application on localhost but i am not able to get app engines data on localhost. I am new to app engine and python so suggest me how to do this on localhost ?

Comment: i wanted to go up the mountain but i couldn't. can you help me?

Comment: Do you know about using [dev_appserver](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver) to run the app locally?

Comment: It's really difficult to understand what you're asking here. Can you explain in detail exactly what you're trying to do, and what problem you run into? Steps that anyone can do to reproduce your problem would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Read and follow the [Google AppEngine Docs on getting started with Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/).